# JPQL Create "Dynamic" Query to execute in repository

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Edit-

I'll add the use case to clear up the function of this.

The user will select two dates - a start date and an end date - these are then passed on and used to select the tables (each year has its own table). In one use case where the two given dates lie in the same year it's a simple query on that table alone.

However, if the two dates are different years I will need to join all tables (so 2011-2013 will be three tables connected, to search through) and thus, I want a dynamic fix to this. I know building up a query like below is against security - just thought something similar would work. As the system will get new tables each year I also dont want to have to manually add however many new queries for each case (2011-2016, 2014-2018, 2011-2019.. etc)

---

I have a question about whether it is possible to create a dynamic query as a String like below and then pass that through to service -> repository, and use that as a query?

```
for (int i = 0; i < yearCondition; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    query += "SELECT md.Device_ID, l.locationRef, " + reportRunForm.getStartDate() + " as 'From Date', "
                            + reportRunForm.getEndDate() + " as 'To Date' "
                            + "from mData.meterdata" + iDateStart.substring(0, 4)
                            + " join MOL2.meters m on device_ID = m.meterUI "
                            + "join MOL2.locations l on m.locationID = l.locationID "
                            + "join MOL2.meterreg mr on m.meterID = mr.meterID "
                            + "where mr.userID = ?1";
                }
                query += "UNION SELECT md.Device_ID, l.locationRef, " + reportRunForm.getStartDate() + " as 'From Date', "
                        + reportRunForm.getEndDate() + " as 'To Date' "
                        + "from mData.meterdata" + (Integer.parseInt(iDateStart.substring(0, 4))+i)
                        + " join MOL2.meters m on device_ID = m.meterUI "
                        + "join MOL2.locations l on m.locationID = l.locationID "
                        + "join MOL2.meterreg mr on m.meterID = mr.meterID "
                        + "where mr.userID = ?1";
            }
```

I may have the wrong idea with how this works, and I know I could create and persist a query through entitymanager, but wanted to know whether doing it through the repository would be possible?

My thought was I'd build up the query like above, pass it through to service and then to repository, and bind it as value in @Query annotation but this doesn't seem possible. I'm likely approaching this wrong so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit -

Had a goof. Understand doing it at all like that is stupid, an approach to build up something similar is what I'm looking for that is still secure.

Comment: You should *NEVER* add variables to queries directly, always use a prepared statement and variable substitutions to prevent sql injection attacks (see [this post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/what-is-sql-injection) on security.se for more details).

Comment: Yeh in general I use prepared statements it was just this situation I was using a variable - but I see where I goofed.

I can't work out a solution in which I can dynamically prepare this statements though as the tables to be used will change and the number of different queries needed would be too much (think 2010 - 2016, and any number of years between to get data - and it grows an extra year).

Comment: Will you tell me what value is coming dynamically.

Comment: So, on the UI the user will select two dates, a start and end date. The start could be let's say a date in 2011, and end in 2014, because of how the database is each year has its own table so I need to union them before doing a search through data between the specific dates. So at one request it maybe one year (so just one iteration) or with more it will add a union for the next year on and so on. It's just extending the query with the same select just a different "from" ("from mData.meterdata" + (Integer.parseInt(iDateStart.substring(0, 4))+i))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this annotations before your POJO can help

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true)
```

Comment: is the OP using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

for example two tables district and constituency ...

Dynamic query

```
    query += "select *from constituency c  where 1=1";
if(constituencyNumber!=null) 
    query +=" and c.constituency_number like '"+constituencyNumber+"%'";
query += " group by c.district_id";

                         OR

     select *from constituency c  where (c.constituency_number is null or c.constituency_number like '1%') group by c.district_id;
```